# Having result even by non exist inputs

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a text file data set with following format (the separation character is tab).

```
0 762354
1 645645
2 4356743
3 576899063
4 64378
.....
```

that I read it and save it in array by:

```
       for (int klk = 0; klk <= 92159; klk++)
            {
                lineuserori = fileuserori.ReadLine();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lineuserori))
                {
                    string[] valuesiesi = lineitemori.Split('\t');
                    int useridori;
                    foreach (string value in valuesiesi)
                    {
                        useridori = Convert.ToInt32(valuesiesi[1]);
                        d[klk] = useridori;
                    }
                }
            }
```

NOW, I want to read an input and search for it in `array d`, if the number exist in array, I do my calculation, if it is not in array show `MessageBox.Show("Error");`, the problem is, it always show output with every input (even the input does not exist in array) and never show `MessageBox.Show("Error");`

```
   {
                int sc = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_id.Text);
                int n = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_noofrecomm.Text);
                for (int yu = 0; yu <= 92161; yu++)
                {
                    int wer = d[yu];
                    if (wer == sc)
                    {
                        userseq = yu;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (userseq >= 0 && userseq <= 92161)
                {
                    var results = new List<float>(1143600);
                    for (int z = 0; z < 1143600; z++)
                    {
                        results.Add(dotproduct(userseq, z));
                    }
                    var sb1 = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (var resultwithindex in results.Select((r, index) => new { result = r, Index = index }).OrderByDescending(r => r.result).Take(n))
                    {
                        sb1.AppendFormat(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}: {1}", c[resultwithindex.Index], resultwithindex.result);
                        sb1.AppendLine();
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show(sb1.ToString());
                }
                if (userseq < 0 || userseq > 92161)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error");
                }
            }
```

Any idea

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code to create array , is `lineitemori` right?
I think, it should be `lineuserori`.

Replace this:

```
string[] valuesiesi = lineitemori.Split('\t');
```

with:

```
string[] valuesiesi = lineuserori.Split('\t');
```

---

I wrote code below. (some lines uses unknown variables commented out)
Input `762354` to  `txtbx_id` and click button1 then empty MessageBox appeared.
Input `76235` to  `txtbx_id` and click button1 then MessageBox say 'Error'.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    // form have three controls  txtbx_id, txtbx_noofrecomm and button1.

    int[] d = new int[92162];
    string data = 
         "0\t762354\n"
        +"1\t645645\n"
        +"2\t4356743\n"
        +"3\t576899063\n"
        +"4\t64378\n";

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();

        using (var fileuserori = new StringReader(data)) { // use StringReader instead of StreamReader
            string lineuserori = "";

            for (int klk = 0; klk <= 92159; klk++) {
                lineuserori = fileuserori.ReadLine();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lineuserori)) {
                    // string[] valuesiesi = lineitemori.Split('\t');
                    string[] valuesiesi = lineuserori.Split('\t');
                    int useridori;
                    foreach (string value in valuesiesi) {
                        useridori = Convert.ToInt32(valuesiesi[1]);
                        d[klk] = useridori;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var userseq = -1;

        int sc = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_id.Text);
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_noofrecomm.Text);
        for (int yu = 0; yu <= 92161; yu++) {
            int wer = d[yu];
            if (wer == sc) {
                userseq = yu;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (userseq >= 0 && userseq <= 92161) {
            var results = new List<float>(1143600);
            for (int z = 0; z < 1143600; z++) {
                // results.Add(dotproduct(userseq, z));
            }
            var sb1 = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var resultwithindex in results.Select((r, index) => new { result = r, Index = index }).OrderByDescending(r => r.result).Take(n)) {
                // sb1.AppendFormat(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}: {1}", c[resultwithindex.Index], resultwithindex.result);
                // sb1.AppendLine();
            }
            MessageBox.Show(sb1.ToString());
        }
        if (userseq < 0 || userseq > 92161) {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @fliedonion. I tried it but the result is the same as before.